# Processing Java Language - Integer number divisable by 16?

Tags: processing

I have an homework that ask this question :
"Write a function to check if an integer is divisable by 16 and returns to boolean (false or correct)"

I wrote this:

```
void setup()
{
  {
  int i=0
 if(i%16==0)
Printls(i)
  else
  println(+i+" not divisable by 16" 
  }
}
```

But I need help because it's not complete. I just want to say to Processing to ask me to put a number with the keyboard to test. I thought it was "keyPressed==true" but it doesn't work. Any solutions? Thanks.

---

Thanks very much for the explanation. I wrote a new code since my last message but I don't think it's correct also.

```
void setup()
{void keyReleased() {
 int i=0
 if key (i%16==0)
printls(i)
println(+i+" is not divisable by 16" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly do not deface / vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the requirements:

> Write a function to check if an integer is divisable by 16 and returns to boolean (false or correct)

and break it down into really easy to follow steps:

1. write a function (you can learn how to write a function following [Daniel Shiffman's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBo2D3Myo6Q&index=2&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ajGB2OI3hl5DZsD1Fw1WzR) and [Andrew Glassner's](https://vimeopro.com/user16640076/week-3-group-3-functions/video/63183377) video tutorials)
2. write a function that returns a boolean
3. write a function that returns a boolean and takes an integer as an argument
4. write a function that returns a true if the integer argument is divisible by 16

You should learn a bit more about functions with each step progressed and by the end of it you should reach your goal. Your logic (using %) makes sense, it's just a matter practicing more to a hang of the syntax (which faulty in your posted code).

Regarding checking a key, you can have a look at the [keyPressed()](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) function but note that the exercise doesn't require this. It feels keyPressed is a distraction at the moment and you should focus on understanding the syntax for functions first.